PostgreSQL CTE behavior influenced by outer `update` statement: Why?
tl;dr
Why does an update from ... statement make a CTE behave differently than an update where... with subquery statement in postgresql?
Full Context
Disclaimer: The information below has been sanitized to maintain privacy.
While working on a legacy system (about 5 year old design) I have a postgres documents table that looks like this:
create table documents (
    uuid              uuid                     not null primary key,
    data              jsonb                    not null,
    created_dt        timestamp with time zone not null,
    deleted_dt        timestamp with time zone
);

And the information in the data column looks like this roughly:
{
    "uuid": "959bd856-707a-4c5e-a76e-4c1496a6103a",
    "bucket": "fake_cloud_bucket_01",
    "md5Sum": "233ea5afd52636b83cf75f7fd39c1f2a",
    "contentType": "application/pdf",
    "tags": {
        "APPLICATION_UUID": "3e979827-36df-4bb0-9012-22cceb54d5e9",
        "IDENTITY_UUID": "9e137538-b0ad-4322-a6a4-2047bab984e4"
    },
    "createdDate": 1704757787264
}

The application that uses this database has a search by tag feature, so in the original design, an index was added to the documents table like this:
create index documents_tags_idxgin
    on documents using gin ((data -> 'tags'::text) jsonb_path_ops);

Now fast-forward 5 years to today and the documents table has some 20 million rows and a simple query like the one below takes about 3 minutes to finish, which is unacceptable:
select * from documents
where data->'tags'->>'key' = 'IDENTITY_UUID'
  and data->'tags'->>'value' = '9e137538-b0ad-4322-a6a4-2047bab984e4';

To make the search by tag feature perform better, I decided to extract the tags into its own table and apply more performant indices to the data. So now we have a new table called tags and an index for it that looks like this:
create table tags (
    document_uuid uuid not null references documents(uuid) on delete restrict,
    tag text not null check (tag <> ''),
    value text not null check (value <> ''),
    primary key (document_uuid, tag)
);

create index tags_tag_value_idx on tags (tag, value);

With the above addition of the tags table, now this query takes on average single digit milliseconds to return a result:
select D.*
from documents as D
join tags as T on D.uuid = T.document_uuid
where T.tag = 'IDENTITY_UUID'
  and T.value = '9e137538-b0ad-4322-a6a4-2047bab984e4';

The Question
To convert the data from the jsonb tags object in the data column of the documents table to rows in the tags table, I wrote a query that spreads the contents of the tags object for each document into the data to be received as a row in the tags table:
insert into tags (document_uuid, tag, value)
    select D.uuid, T.key, replace((T.value)::text, '"', '')
    from documents as D
        join jsonb_each(data->'tags') as T on true
    where D.tags_processed_on is null
        for update skip locked
    limit 2500
        on conflict do nothing
    returning document_uuid, tag, value

Given the jsonb object in the context part above, there are two rows insert into the tags table and the rows returned by the above query look like this:
document_uuid, tag, value
'959bd856-707a-4c5e-a76e-4c1496a6103a', 'APPLICATION_UUID', '3e979827-36df-4bb0-9012-22cceb54d5e9'
'959bd856-707a-4c5e-a76e-4c1496a6103a', 'IDENTITY_UUID', '9e137538-b0ad-4322-a6a4-2047bab984e4'

In order to keep track of the documents processed, we also added a temporary column to the documents table:
alter table documents add column tags_processed_on timestamp default null;

So my query to insert into the tags table and update documents as processed looked like this:
with docs_to_tags as (
    insert into tags (document_uuid, tag, value)
        select D.uuid, T.key, replace((T.value)::text, '"', '')
        from documents as D
            join jsonb_each(data->'tags') as T on true
        where D.tags_processed_on is null
            for update skip locked
        limit 2500
            on conflict do nothing
        returning document_uuid, tag, value
)
update documents as D1
set tags_processed_on = now()
from docs_to_tags as DTT
where D1.uuid = DTT.document_uuid;

The problem with the above CTE is that when I ran it, it would only insert the first tag for any given document and move on to the next document. But when I used a subquery with the outer update statement, then the insert into the tags table behaved like I expected, inserting all tags into the tags table. So the CTE that works looks like this:
with docs_to_tags as (
    insert into tags (document_uuid, tag, value)
        select D.uuid, T.key, replace((T.value)::text, '"', '')
        from documents as D
            join jsonb_each(data->'tags') as T on true
        where D.tags_processed_on is null
            for update skip locked
        limit 2500
            on conflict do nothing
        returning document_uuid, tag, value
)
update documents as D1
set tags_processed_on = now()
where D1.uuid in (
    select distinct D2.document_uuid
    from docs_to_tags as D2
);

So finally my question is this:
Why does an update from ... statement make a CTE behave differently than an update where... with subquery statement in postgresql?
... or more succinctly: Why does the outer update statement have any influence on what is returned by the inner insert query inside of the CTE?

Update 2024-06-04 23:30:31 PST
Adding output of EXPLAIN (COSTS OFF) as requested by @laurenz-albe:
Cost of CTE with update from ... statement
Update on documents d1
  CTE docs_to_tags
    ->  Insert on document_tags
          Conflict Resolution: NOTHING
          ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"
                ->  Limit
                      ->  LockRows
                            ->  Nested Loop
                                  ->  Seq Scan on documents d
                                        Filter: (tags_processed_on IS NULL)
                                  ->  Function Scan on jsonb_each t
  ->  Nested Loop
        ->  CTE Scan on docs_to_tags dtt
        ->  Index Scan using documents_pkey on documents d1
              Index Cond: (uuid = dtt.document_uuid)

Cost of CTE with update where... with subquery statement
Update on documents d2
  CTE docs_to_tags
    ->  Insert on document_tags
          Conflict Resolution: NOTHING
          ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"
                ->  Limit
                      ->  LockRows
                            ->  Nested Loop
                                  ->  Seq Scan on documents d1
                                        Filter: (tags_processed_on IS NULL)
                                  ->  Function Scan on jsonb_each t1
  ->  Nested Loop
        ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"
              ->  HashAggregate
                    Group Key: d3.document_uuid
                    ->  CTE Scan on docs_to_tags d3
        ->  Index Scan using documents_pkey on documents d2
              Index Cond: (uuid = "ANY_subquery".document_uuid)


Could you add EXPLAIN (COSTS OFF) output to the question? That might explain why.
